# RN Navigation - BottomTabHeader current screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have the following React Native navigation architecture:
[image]

[image]

Im trying to set the styling on a button in my TabHeader component (see blue arrow) based on which Screen I am on. However in the props passed into it by TabNavigator, I am only seeing the Stack directly beneath it, in this scenario the HomeStack.

Is it possible to get the current Screen (Home) in TabNavigator even when it is 2 levels deep?  (Core -> HomeStack -> Home)

Answer (score 0):

[Source](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution/#setting-parent-screen-options-based-on-child-navigators-state)

```
You can only modify navigation options for a navigator from one of its screen components. This applies equally to navigators that are nested as screens.
```

On the same page there is a title [Setting parent screen options based on child navigator's state​](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution#setting-parent-screen-options-based-on-child-navigators-state)